# Dreamweaver PHP Include Files "not found"

Tags: php, dreamweaver

OK, weird problem. Hopefully it's something easy and that I'm just missing it.

I have the beginnings of a new PHP page being developed in Dreamweaver. In it I make references to 3 include files, 2 of them being required_once.

DW recognizes the include code and list the files along the top after "source code", however, when I try to view the code by clicking on their names at the top, I get "'file' is not on the local disk. Nor will DW recognize any code inside these include files.
And, yes, I have verified several times that the folders are spelled right and where the root directory is.

Also, it doesn't happen on every page. Other pages in the same directory, with the exact same includes, work fine.

Any ideas?

```
<?php require_once('/connections/TECA_DB.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('/connections/temp.php'); ?>
<?php include("/includes/header.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: might sound silly, did you refreshed site root ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it shouldn't matter, but try adding "." in front of your first slash, in case it isn't specified in your include path.

```
<?php require_once('./connections/TECA_DB.php'); ?> 
<?php require_once('./connections/temp.php'); ?> 
<?php include("./includes/header.php"); ?>
```

and ensure all files are saved so it knows where the relativity exists.

Comment: OK, that worked, but still doesn't answer the question of why. I was using absolute paths rather than relative, but verified using a script where it thought the root was. 
Plus other pages with the same include weren't affected.

I'd like to understand better what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: why is a great question, but a not so simple answer.  I ran into this several versions of DW ago, and have simply got into the habit of doing full path with http and all, or specifying the applicable . or .. annotation in front of the first slash.  No real answer as to why, but once the habit is established, it wont hurt anything and will keep the problem from surfacing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to see the `.php` files in the browser than the `PHP` parser is never being called by the server. You shouldn't be able to see the files in the client browser. What is the extension of your file? Is it `.html` or is it `.php`?